# Add get parameter ONLY value, with existing keys?

Tags: django, forms, url, parameters, get

I'm using form with python&django.

I want to append get parameter, for only it's value.

For example, I want to this result (`%2C` means `%`)

`?order_status__in=1%2C2`

So that I can receive 1 or 2 both for `order_status` get key.

But when I submit form, my get params go like this

`?order_status__in=1&order_status__in=2`

How can I append only get param's value, not whole keys?

Below is my `form` example. (using `django`)

```
          <form action="" method="GET" id="customForm">
            {% for s in status %}
            <label for="{{ s.id }}" style="display: inline;">
              <input type="checkbox" value="{{ s.id }}" name="order_status__in" id="{{ s.id }}"{% if s.get_str_id in request.GET.order_status__in %}checked{% endif %}
              >
              {{ s.title }}</label>
            {% endfor %}
            <input type="submit" value="search">
          </form>
```

Comment: I don't understand why you want that. What's wrong with what you have? You can get the values via `request.GET.getlist('order_status__in')`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks for your comment. I knew that's easy way but I use django admin, and only `get` works (like above) in django admin filter so I want to do that.

Comment: Also I have curiosity about that way - why almost every `GET` method use like that (list - shaped).  So I ask this question.